# Why i can't include scene header in Cocos2d-x

Tags: visual-c++, cocos2d-x

Using cocos2dx. Create .h and .cpp file of new scene. But can't to include it to main scene. 
`Error: Can't find source file "LevelSelect.h"`.

Here's files.
LevelSelect.h

```
#ifndef LEVEL_SELECT_H_
#define LEVEL_SELECT_H_
#include "cocos2d.h"

/**
 * LevelSelector
 */
class LevelSelect : public cocos2d::CCScene
{
public:
    virtual bool init();  
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
    void backCallback(CCObject* pSender);
    CREATE_FUNC(LevelSelect);
};
#endif
```

LevelSelect.cpp

```
#include "LevelSelect.h"
#include "AppMacros.h"

USING_NS_CC;

/**
 * Level Select scene
 */

CCScene* LevelSelect::scene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    LevelSelect *layer = LevelSelect::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
bool LevelSelect::init(){
        CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();
    CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize(); 

CCSprite* pSprite = CCSprite::create("resources/main/01_bg.png");


pSprite->setPosition(ccp(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));
    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(pSprite, 0);
    return true;
    }
```

trying to switch scenes using this code

```
void MainMenu::menuNewGameCallback(CCObject* pSender){
     CCScene *pScene = LevelSelect::scene();
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(pScene); 
}
```

what is invalid? why i can't use `LevelSelect::scene();`? how to correctly write scene and call it from main menu?

Comment: If the compiler cannot find a file, its contents are unimportant. You have to check where are your files and, specifically, whether the location of `LevelSelect.h` is specified in the compiler path.

Comment: the same directory with mainmenu scene. but i can't call it

Comment: The important point her is whether it can be accessed when compiling `LevelSelect.cpp`, which is the file that includes it.

Comment: how to resolve that? what changes should i make?

Comment: Go to your project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Properties. In the line *Include Directories* you should have the directory where `LevelSelect.h` is. If it is not there, add it.

Comment: if they are in the same filter-folder of project they must be easily to access aren't it? In properties they are avaliable

Comment: If both `LevelSelect.h` and `LevelSelect.cpp` are in the same folder, you should have no problem. If this is the case, I don't know why you are getting that error message.

Comment: header and cpp are correct? maybe something wrong with implementation?

Comment: moved class from `LevelSelect.h` to main scene header - works great. It's kinda curse on cocos...

Comment: It was my project setup issue in VS. No special cases here, just add file to project